# SQL CASE WHEN Date

Tags: sql, sas, case

I am trying to create a table that gives me the number of users that have accessed an app within the last  3 months as follows:

last 3 months: (number)
last 2 months: (number)
last month: (number)

the number is coming from another table result that has the value day_p which indicates the day the unique user accessed the app. I just want to place them within the month frame. Below is the code I am trying to run, but I keep getting an error that name is expected, but I have named them as 'Three_Month', 'Two_Month', 'Last_Month'.

```
CREATE TABLE Last_Access AS 
   SELECT
   count(CASE WHEN t1.day_p BETWEEN '20210518' AND '20210618' THEN 1 END) AS 'THREE_MONTH',
   count(CASE WHEN t1.day_p BETWEEN '20210619' AND '20210718' THEN 1 END) AS 'TWO_MONTH',
   count(CASE WHEN t1.day_p BETWEEN '20210719' AND '20210819' THEN 1 END) AS 'LAST_MONTH',
   End
   FROM Result AS t1;
```

Any suggestions / tips would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Your query is malformed, last `End` is wrong (and also its previous comma...)

Answer (score 0):

To create a TABLE you need to give your variables **names**.  You could also attach a label to the variable if you wanted.  You don't need to include the `label=` keyword, but I find it makes it clearer what the string is there for.

```
CREATE TABLE Last_Access AS 
   SELECT
    count(CASE WHEN t1.day_p BETWEEN '20210518' AND '20210618' THEN 1 END)
      AS THREE_MONTH LABEL='THREE_MONTH'
   ,count(CASE WHEN t1.day_p BETWEEN '20210619' AND '20210718' THEN 1 END)
      AS TWO_MONTH LABEL='TWO_MONTH'
   FROM Result AS t1
;
```

PS Don't put continuation characters at the end of the lines.  Places them at the start of the line and you will be less likely to include an extra one like in your example because they will be more visible to the humans reading the code.